# Haskell: Removing tuples from 1 list based on contents of another

Tags: haskell, filtering

I have a problem where I am trying to filter(remove) the elements in one list that are contained in another list. Both lists contain tuples. My idea of how to do this is something as follows:

```
map solutions.filter (\(x,y) -> (x,y) notElem) forced --Trying to remove elements from solutions that are also in forced.
```

I'm sorry if this is a silly question. I'm just learning haskell and still wrapping my brain around list filters.

Edit: It occurs to me that actually, I am trying to remove all `(x,*) and (*,y)` except for the (x,y) pair in the forced list

Sample: Forced= [(A,1)]
Solutions= [(A,1),(A,2),(A,3),(B,1),(B,2),(B,3)]
what I want to create is a new list that removes all the tuples where 1 is being assigned to a task other than A or A is being assigned to a task other than 1.
So the result would look like
[(A,1),(B,2),(B,3)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data.List has [the `(\\)` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-):

```
import Data.List ((\\))

a = [5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 1, 4]
b = [7, 2, 4]
a \\ b -- [5, 6, 8, 1]
```

---

For your tuple thing, I suppose you could do:

```
[(a, b) | (a, b) <- solutions, not $ any (\(c, d) -> (a == c && b /= d) || (a /= c && b == d)) forced]
```

Comment: Thanks. Although after doing some work, I realize my problem is actually slightly more advanced. See edit

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread, but this code just freezes haskell into a loop

Comment: @user979616: How many do you have? It’s not an infinite loop, but it’s O(mn).

Comment: 8!. Haskell just detects this and refuses to print out my list. Although I'm assuming it can still be operated on and if that's the case, that's okay

Comment: @user979616: [Well, it seems to terminate.](http://codepad.org/06LXRdEs) 8 items in each list?